# Syncing Red Hat 7 Repo in Spacewalk

Tags: redhat, centos7, repository, spacewalk

While setting up my Spacewalk server I have ran into problems syncing Red Hat Server RPMs.

My Repository Details are as follows:

```
**Repo Label:** redhat_7.x86_64
**Repo URL:** https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/server7/x86_64/
**Repo type:** yum
**SSL Certificates:** Used from an old machine with a Red Hat entitlement.
```

When I add the repo to a channel and try to sync it up, I get the following output:

```
2019/04/30 08:12:39 -04:00 Command: ['/usr/bin/spacewalk-repo-sync', '--channel', 'arts_redhat_7.x86_64', '--type', 'yum']
2019/04/30 08:12:39 -04:00 Sync of channel started.
2019/04/30 08:12:39 -04:00 
2019/04/30 08:12:39 -04:00   Processing repository with URL: https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/server7/x86_64/
2019/04/30 08:12:39 -04:00 ERROR: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from redhat_7.x86_64_base: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/server7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
2019/04/30 08:12:39 -04:00 ERROR: failure: repodata/repomd.xml from redhat_7.x86_64_base: [Errno 256] No more mirrors to try.
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/server7/x86_64/repodata/repomd.xml: [Errno 14] HTTPS Error 403 - Forbidden
2019/04/30 08:12:40 -04:00 Sync of channel completed in 0:00:00.
```

For more information on the setup, the Spacewalk server is running CentOS 7 and Spacewalk 2.9. Spacewalk's documentation links directly to [this Red Hat Satellite document](https://access.redhat.com/documentation/en-us/red_hat_satellite/5.7/html/client_configuration_guide/index), which I haven't had any luck with.

From what I've read in the Spacewalk mailing list this type of setup used to work. Do I need a *new* Red Hat Satellite specific entitlement, or is there something I'm missing?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like the URL is wrong, 
try this URL 
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/extras/os   for extras 
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/optional/os  For optional
https://cdn.redhat.com/content/dist/rhel/server/7/7Server/x86_64/os          For base